# IIS showing default page when website stopped intead of sending 404 error when behind load balancer F5

Tags: iis, load, load-balancing, f5, applicationpoolidentity

On dev server when I take website down , I am getting 404 on browsing web site. After promoting application to Stage or PAT server (which is equivalent to PROD env) F5 fail over is failing because when website is made down (stopped) F5 is not gettting 404 from the node 1( from the IIS server) instead it is redirecting to IIS default page and F5 is not switiching to node 2.
Please help.

To do some reverse engineering, now I am trying to get default page on dev enviroment. But its always sending 404 when website is stopped. Any options that I can try to get default page in Dev environment. Any help is appreciated !!.

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause. Default web site and my web site was set at same IP address and port 80. When my web site is down(stopped) iis is defaulting to default web site page.